# What does RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 mean in RewriteRule directive in htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, rules

I have found similar but not exactly. If someone can explain why this plus sign (`+`) is used in the following.

I found information about`^(.*)`, but not `^(.+)`.

I need some more clarification for why is this *plus sign* used. And what it means when used in the following:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1
```

Comment: You actually want to read a bit about what "regular expressions" are. There is _tons_ of documentation for that, great books, you can study. It is one of the most fundamental tools of complexity theory, often used in practical computer science.

Answer (score 2):

There are two aspects to this question:

1. The interpretation of the regular expression (regex) `^(.*)` vs `^(.+)`
2. The use of the regex in the `RewriteRule` directive in `.htaccess`.

**tl;dr** Yes, the two regex have different meanings. However, the use of one or the other in the `RewriteRule` directive in `.htaccess` makes no real difference.

---

#### The regex

> ```
> ^(.+)/$
> ```

The `*` and `+` are *quantifiers*, meaning "0 or more" and "1 or more" of the preceding group respectively.

The `.` (dot) is a special meta-character that matches any character (except newlines).

So, `.*` matches 0 or more "any characters" and `.+` matches 1 or more "any characters". (Which must then be followed by a slash.)

The `^` and `$` are *anchors* that assert the "start" and "end" of the string respectively, so `^(.+)/$` is matching URL-paths that end in a slash, *capturing* the part of the URL-path *before* the trailing slash. The `^` prefix is strictly optional since regex is greedy by default.

#### `RewriteRule` in `.htaccess`

> RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1

When in `.htaccess`, it does not matter whether you use `*` or `+` here since the `/` (slash) will never appear at the start of the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. (Even multiple slashes at the start of the URL-path are *resolved-away* before the `RewriteRule` *pattern* is applied.)

However, if this directive was used in a *server* or *virtualhost* context (ie. not `.htaccess` or `<Directory>` containers in the server config) then you would *need* to use `+` in order to prevent the slash at the start of the URL-path (when requesting the *root* directory) being matched.

But... this directive as written is incomplete. This should probably be an external redirect (but it is missing an `R` flag), and consequently, will need a `RewriteBase` directive (unless the *substitution* string is modified to include a slash prefix).